# Вывод иерархии папки

Tags: java

Есть задача:

> Запросить путь на папку с консоли, получить список всех папок заданной папки с учетом иерархии.

Например, поиск в папке "book" даст 5 элементов:

```
-book
--directory1
---file1
---file2
--directory2
---directory3
----directory4
-----directory5
------file3
```

Частичная реализация выглядит так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String scan = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    System.out.println(scan);
    File dir = new File(String.valueOf(scan));
    if ( dir.isDirectory() ) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for ( File tmpFile : files ) {
            System.out.println("-" + tmpFile.getName());
            if ( tmpFile.isDirectory() ) {
                File[] tmpFile1 = tmpFile.listFiles();
                for ( File file3 : tmpFile1 ) {
                    System.out.println("--" + file3.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
d://book
-directory1
--file1.txt
--file2.txt
-directory2
--directory3
```

Результат выдает данные только до третьей директории, и ума не приложу как исправить код и довести задачу до конца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо рекурсии можно использовать стек:

```
private static class Element
{
    public final String indent;
    public final File file;

    public Element(String indent, File file)
    {
        this.indent = indent;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return indent + file.getName();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String path = scanner.nextLine();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory())
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect directory name");
    }
    Deque<Element> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    stack.add(new Element("-", dir));
    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        Element element = stack.pollLast();
        System.out.println(element);
        if (element.file.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files = element.file.listFiles();
            for (int i = files.length - 1; i >=0; i--)
            {
                stack.add(new Element(element.indent + "-", files[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Идея остаётся та же: берём очередной файл/директорию, выводим на экран, после чего, если это директория, добавляем в обработку содержимое этой папки. И так до тех пор, пока есть что обрабатывать.

Comment: отличная мысль использовать стек)
всё получилось лучшим образом. Спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

В стандартной библиотеке есть замечательный класс `Files`, в нем есть статический метод `walkFileTree`. Он нужен именно для того, что вы хотите. Т.е. для обхода дерева каталогов.

Код будет следующий:

```
Path parent = Paths.get("<корневая директория>");
Files.walkFileTree(parent, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

     @Override
     public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
         int count = dir.getNameCount() - parent.getNameCount() + 1;
         count += dir.getFileName().toString().length();

         //выравнивание по правому краю
         String text = String.format("%" + count + "s", dir.getFileName());
         text = text.replaceAll("[\\s]", "-");
         System.out.println(text);
         return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Не поверите, полчаса голову ломал, так и не смог придумать решение без рекурсии. Вот код, который у меня получился

```
public class Main
{
static String counter = "-";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Путь к папке");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String path = s.nextLine();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists()){
        System.out.println("Папки с введеным именем не существует");
    }
    else if(!dir.isDirectory()){
        System.out.println("Не является папкой");
    }
    else {
        printAllFilesFromDirectory(dir);
    }
}

static void printAllFilesFromDirectory(File dir){
    for(File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        print(file);
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            counter += "-";
            printAllFilesFromDirectory(file);
        }
    }
    counter -= "-";
}

static void print(File file){
    System.out.println(counter + " " + file.getName());
}
}
```

После проверок "на дурака" введеный путь передается в метод `printAllFilesFromDirectory`. В нем каждый файл передается методу `print()`, в котором выводятся тире и его имя. Количество тире опрелеляется счетчиком `counter` (его значение по умолчанию равно единице). После метода `print` если файл является директорией мы инкрементируем счетчик, так как уровень иерархии увеличился. После этого мы выполняем метод с помощью рекурсии и передаем ему директорию.

В итоге этот метод будет выводить все файлы и директории с учетом иерархии. Обратите внимание на декремент `counter`. Он происходит когда все файлы будут выведены! (Директории - нет, в этом случае происходит рекурсия)

Да, знаю, если путь будет слишком большой, то рекурсия станет причиной переполнения стека. Повторюсь: я не смог придумать другое решение :)

**UPDATE**

Теперь `counter` это строка (метод `print` выглядел по-уродски.